# Move_base Costmaps vs. NavFn Costmap

Tags: navigation, costmap, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When using standard PR2 Navigation (`roslaunch pr2_2dnav pr2_2dnav.launch`) there are three costmaps listed.

```
 $> rostopic list | grep /obstacles
 /move_base_node/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/obstacles
 /move_base_node/global_costmap/obstacles
 /move_base_node/local_costmap/obstacles
```

Why does `Navfn` (which is the global planner) get its own costmap? Shouldn't it just use `global_costmap`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37882/move_base-costmaps-vs.-navfn-costmap/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2012-07-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Navfn uses the same global costmal as the local planner. The topics are just for publishing (e.g. for debugging), navfn does not get the costmap via that topic.

By default navfn does not publish anything on that topic. You can imagine that it is possible to use navfn without move_base, having its own topics is for such cases, maybe.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2